# Different ways to create this String in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Disclaimer: Yes, this is homework and yes, I have already solved it.

**Task:** Create the String `"0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"` <- Note, no whitespace

Obviously not using direct assignment, but using tools such as loops, ranges, splitting and such. I already finished this using a 10-increment loop, and I am pretty sure there are way more intelligent ways to solve it and I am curious about the alternatives.
How would you build a String like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is using [`Range#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-step) and [`Array#*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-2A):

```
(0..100).step(10).to_a * " "
# => "0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
```

Comment: So `* " "` is just a shorthand version of `Array.join()`?

Comment: Note that the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) suggest to favor the use of `Array#join` over `Array#*` with a string argument.

Comment: That's basically all it says as well, `Favor the use of Array#join over the fairly cryptic Array#* with a string argument.`, odd. If readibility is the only argument against it then at least there's nothing wrong.

Comment: The style-guide recommends `join` over `*` because more people are familiar with `join`. That's not a great reason to avoid the use of an operator since at some point `join` wasn't familiar to people either.

Answer (score 3):

Second version using [`Range#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-step):

```
(0..100).step(10).to_a.join(' ')
# "0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
```

Comment: `(0..100).step(10).to_a.join(' ')` enough... no need to do string interpolation..

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different and not use `#step`:

```
(0..10).map{|x| x * 10}.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) would work, too (here with a Ruby 2.1 style hash argument)

```
0.step(by: 10).take(11).join(' ')
#=> "0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
```

Comment: Interesting with a verbose alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be contrary, here are some using `times` with `map`, `with_object` and `inject`:

```
10.times.map{ |i| "#{ 10 * (i + 1) }" }.join(' ') # => "10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
10.times.with_object([]) { |i, o| o << "#{ 10 * (i + 1) }" }.join(' ') # => "10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
10.times.inject([]) { |o, i| o << "#{ 10 * (i + 1) }" }.join(' ') # => "10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
```